# "SQLSTATE[42000]:Syntax error or access violation:1064You have anerror in your SQLsyntax;

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an problem in the LARAVEL
I want to make a selection of phones and after filling a form. So I have the genre (phone, tablet), the brand (samsung, oppo ...) and the type (S10 +, S3S ...) and I want to pass the mark and gender parameter to fill the form. but when I go to show the guy it gives me a problem.

Controller :

```
public function affiche(){
    $listgenre = DB::select('select distinct genre_mobile from mobiles');
    return view('reparation.reparation', ['mobiles' => $listgenre]);
}

//affiche la page des marques après le genre 
public function affichemarque($genre){
    $listmarque = DB::select('
                    select distinct marque_mobile , genre_mobile from mobiles where genre_mobile = ?', [$genre]); 
    return view('reparation.marque', ['mobiles' => $listmarque]);
}

//Affiche Type of mobile après la marque
public function affichetype($genre, $marque){
$listtype = DB::select('select * from mobiles where genre_mobile = '.$genre.'and marque_mobile='.$marque);
    return view('reparation.type', ['mobiles' => $listtype]);
}
```

routes :

```
Route::get('reparation/rep', 'AppController@affiche'); //page choix telephone or tablette

Route::get('reparation/{genre}/marque', 'AppController@affichemarque'); //choix des marques (samsung, oppo, apple ...)

Route::get('reparation/{genre}/{marque}/type', 'AppController@affichetype'); //type( S3, S10+, s70 ...)
```

The probleeem :

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'marque_mobile=SAMSUNG' at line 1 (SQL: select * from mobiles where
>   genre_mobile = telephoneand marque_mobile=SAMSUNG) ◀"

Comment: Try adding double quote on genre_mobile  and marque_mobile `DB::select('select * from mobiles where genre_mobile = "'.$genre.'" and marque_mobile = "'.$marque.'"');` also need an space after the and

Comment: What @AgeValed said, except I'll recommend you don't use this in any production code as it's very unsafe. You should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: I agreed with @Jamie-FenrirDigitalLtd, I always recommend to use query builder -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries try to don't use raw SQL queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL: select * from mobiles where genre_mobile = telephoneand marque_mobile=SAMSUNG
```

if you read the SQL query well, you will see that you need to add a space between AND and marque_mobile

```php
$listtype = DB::select('select * from mobiles where genre_mobile = '.$genre.' and marque_mobile = '.$marque);
```

to avoid these errors, always write keywords in uppercase and try to concatenate using this method or using named bindings:

```php
$listtype = DB::select("SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE genre_mobile = {$genre} AND marque_mobile = {$marque}" );
```

```php
$listtype = DB::select("SELECT * FROM mobiles WHERE genre_mobile = :genre AND marque_mobile = :marque",['genre' => $genre, 'marque' => $marque]);
```

also, I advise you to use Eloquent, it's much better to read, and you avoid writing big SQL queries.

Comment: He gave me another error, even though the table is filled in the database : "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'telephone' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from mobiles where genre_mobile = telephone and marque_mobile = HUAWEI) ◀"

Comment: Check my comment, you need to add double quotes.

Comment: you should avoid classic concatenation, use the named bindings method.

Comment: Thank You BrO, I found the solution : 
    
$listtype = DB::select("select * from `mobiles` where `genre_mobile` like '$genre' and `marque_mobile` like '$marque'");